# Nesting a list of dictionaries based on key

Tags: python, parsing, recursion, lisp

I'm writing a tiny lisp interpreter as a learning exercise in Python. I have a set of functions that parses a string of Lisp code into a list of dictionaries. For example, for the following text:

```
(defun hello-name (name) 
  (quote (+ "Hello, " name)))
```

The parser function will output:

```
[{'type': 'identifier', 'value': '('},
 {'type': 'identifier', 'value': 'defun'},
 {'type': 'identifier', 'value': 'hello-name'},
 {'type': 'identifier', 'value': '('},
 {'type': 'identifier', 'value': 'name'},
 {'type': 'identifier', 'value': ')'},
 {'type': 'identifier', 'value': '('},
 {'type': 'identifier', 'value': 'quote'},
 {'type': 'identifier', 'value': '('},
 {'type': 'identifier', 'value': '+'},
 {'type': 'string_literal', 'value': 'Hello, '},
 {'type': 'identifier', 'value': 'name'},
 {'type': 'identifier', 'value': ')'},
 {'type': 'identifier', 'value': ')'},
 {'type': 'identifier', 'value': ')'}]
```

I would like it to be such that it nests the identifiers based on how many opening brackets have come before it, for example, the output of the parser should be like this:

```
[
    {'type': 'identifier', 'value': 'defun'},
    {'type': 'identifier', 'value': 'hello-name'},
        [ 
            {'type': 'identifier', 'value': 'name'},
        ] 
            
        [ 
            {'type': 'identifier', 'value': 'quote'},
                [
                    {'type': 'identifier', 'value': '+'},
                    {'type': 'string_literal', 'value': 'Hello, '},
                    {'type': 'identifier', 'value': 'name'},
                ]
        ]
]
```

The difference here is that each occurence of "(" or ")" has been replaced with one more nesting into the list.

How would I do this in Python?

Comment: Whats your code for now?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: the example code you showed quotes some computation, making the variable "name" unused  in the function (only the constant symbol "name" would be used), that's not important for parsing here, but this is somewhat confusing

Comment: No implementation of any *bona fide* Lisp puts out a parse tree that still includes parenthesis tokens.

Answer (score 1):

While you should've incldued some of the code that you've tried yourself, you are a beginer, and this is a semi-challenging problem, so have some help.

This is a pretty standard token parsing approach, essentially tracking the number of open brackets, items within open brackets are placed in an array to be evaluated recursively, items on the top level outside the brackets are returned unchanged. Opening and closing brackets are discarded.

```
def reduce(parsed_expression):
    nested = []
    open_count = 0
    for line in parsed_expression:
        if line["type"] == "identifier" and line["value"] == "(":
            open_count += 1
            if open_count == 1:     # First opening bracket
                continue        # Discard opening bracket
        elif line["type"] == "identifier" and line["value"] == ")":
            open_count -= 1
            if open_count == 0:     # Closing all brackets
                yield list(reduce(nested))  # Evaluate nested expression
                nested = []
                continue

        if open_count == 0:
            yield line   # Return item unchanged
        if open_count > 0:
            nested.append(line)    # Add to nested expression
```

If you call it like this:

```
expression = [{'type': 'identifier', 'value': '('},
              {'type': 'identifier', 'value': 'defun'},
              {'type': 'identifier', 'value': 'hello-name'},
              {'type': 'identifier', 'value': '('},
              {'type': 'identifier', 'value': 'name'},
              {'type': 'identifier', 'value': ')'},
              {'type': 'identifier', 'value': '('},
              {'type': 'identifier', 'value': 'quote'},
              {'type': 'identifier', 'value': '('},
              {'type': 'identifier', 'value': '+'},
              {'type': 'string_literal', 'value': 'Hello, '},
              {'type': 'identifier', 'value': 'name'},
              {'type': 'identifier', 'value': ')'},
              {'type': 'identifier', 'value': ')'},
              {'type': 'identifier', 'value': ')'}]

res = list(reduce(expression))
```

You get this result:

```
exp = [[
    {'type': 'identifier', 'value': 'defun'},
    {'type': 'identifier', 'value': 'hello-name'},
    [
        {'type': 'identifier', 'value': 'name'}
    ],
    [
        {'type': 'identifier', 'value': 'quote'},
        [
            {'type': 'identifier', 'value': '+'},
            {'type': 'string_literal', 'value': 'Hello, '},
            {'type': 'identifier', 'value': 'name'}
        ]
    ]
]]
```

Note two things: you have to put `reduce` into `list` because it is a generator, and you want to collapse it into a list. Also, it is slightly different than what you expected, because of the top level `(` `)`s

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive generator function:

```
def to_ast(s):
   while (n:=next(s, None)) is not None and n['value'] != ')':
      if n['value'] != '(':
         yield n
      else:
         yield list(to_ast(s))

tokens = [{'type': 'identifier', 'value': '('}, {'type': 'identifier', 'value': 'defun'}, {'type': 'identifier', 'value': 'hello-name'}, {'type': 'identifier', 'value': '('}, {'type': 'identifier', 'value': 'name'}, {'type': 'identifier', 'value': ')'}, {'type': 'identifier', 'value': '('}, {'type': 'identifier', 'value': 'quote'}, {'type': 'identifier', 'value': '('}, {'type': 'identifier', 'value': '+'}, {'type': 'string_literal', 'value': 'Hello, '}, {'type': 'identifier', 'value': 'name'}, {'type': 'identifier', 'value': ')'}, {'type': 'identifier', 'value': ')'}, {'type': 'identifier', 'value': ')'}]
print(list(to_ast(iter(tokens)))[0])
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "type": "identifier",
        "value": "defun"
    },
    {
        "type": "identifier",
        "value": "hello-name"
    },
    [
        {
            "type": "identifier",
            "value": "name"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "type": "identifier",
            "value": "quote"
        },
        [
            {
                "type": "identifier",
                "value": "+"
            },
            {
                "type": "string_literal",
                "value": "Hello, "
            },
            {
                "type": "identifier",
                "value": "name"
            }
        ]
    ]
]
```